# Shuffle songs across albums on Google Play that have been downloaded to Android phone

Tags: google-play-music

I'm new to Google Play and have just downloaded a good bit of my music to Android phone. I like to shuffle but am dismayed to find the only facility for shuffling appears to be within album and not across albums (may be specific to downloaded tracks).

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to play all the songs you have, in shuffle, simply open Google Play Music. Open the menu -> Music library -> Shuffle all.

If you want to shuffle between specific songs, find the desired songs, press on the three dots next to the name of the song, and click on 'Add to playlist' -> New playlist. After adding all your desired songs or albums, go to the playlists tab, and next to your newly created playlist, press on the three dots -> Shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

On Google Play Music version 8.16.7620-1.J

Menu -> Music library -> **Songs** -> Shuffle all

As far as tabs go, I only see a shuffle switch on the Songs tab. Would be nice on to have that ability on Artist and Genre, but I don't see it.